# How to access Spring-boot JMX remotely

Tags: spring, spring-boot, jmx

I know that spring automatically expose JMX beans. I was able to access it locally using VisualVM.

However on prod how I can connect to remotely to the app using it's JMX beans? Is there a default port or should I define anything in addition?

Thanks,
ray.

Answer (score 60, accepted):

By default JMX is automatically accessible locally, so running `jconsole` *locally* would detect all your local java apps without port exposure.

To access an app via JMX *remotely* you have to specify an RMI Registry port. The thing to know is that when connecting, JMX initializes on that port and ***then*** establishes a data connection back on a **random high** port, which is a huge problem if you have a firewall in the middle. ("Hey sysadmins, just open up everything, mkay?").

To force JMX to connect back on the same port as you've established, you have a couple of the following options. Note: you can use different ports for JMX and RMI or you can use the same port.

**Option 1: Command line**

```
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=$JMX_REGISTRY_PORT 
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.rmi.port=$RMI_SERVER_PORT
```

If you're using Spring Boot you can put this in your `(appname).conf` file that lives alongside your `(appname).jar` deployment.

**Option 2: Tomcat/Tomee configuration**

Configure a [JmxRemoteLifecycleListener](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/config/listeners.html#JMX_Remote_Lifecycle_Listener_-_org.apache.catalina.mbeans.JmxRemoteLifecycleListener):

Maven Jar:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
        <artifactId>tomcat-catalina-jmx-remote</artifactId>
        <version>8.5.9</version>
        <type>jar</type>
    </dependency>
```

Configure your server.xml:

```
<Listener className="org.apache.catalina.mbeans.JmxRemoteLifecycleListener"
      rmiRegistryPortPlatform="10001" rmiServerPortPlatform="10002" />
```

**Option 3: configure programmatically**

```
@Configuration
public class ConfigureRMI {

    @Value("${jmx.rmi.host:localhost}")
    private String rmiHost;

    @Value("${jmx.rmi.port:1099}")
    private Integer rmiPort;

    @Bean
    public RmiRegistryFactoryBean rmiRegistry() {
        final RmiRegistryFactoryBean rmiRegistryFactoryBean = new RmiRegistryFactoryBean();
        rmiRegistryFactoryBean.setPort(rmiPort);
        rmiRegistryFactoryBean.setAlwaysCreate(true);
        return rmiRegistryFactoryBean;
    }

    @Bean
    @DependsOn("rmiRegistry")
    public ConnectorServerFactoryBean connectorServerFactoryBean() throws Exception {
        final ConnectorServerFactoryBean connectorServerFactoryBean = new ConnectorServerFactoryBean();
        connectorServerFactoryBean.setObjectName("connector:name=rmi");
        connectorServerFactoryBean.setServiceUrl(String.format("service:jmx:rmi://%s:%s/jndi/rmi://%s:%s/jmxrmi", rmiHost, rmiPort, rmiHost, rmiPort));
        return connectorServerFactoryBean;
    }
}
```

The trick, you'll see, is the `serviceUrl` in which you specify both the jmx:rmi host/port and the jndi:rmi host/port. If you specify both, you won't get the random high "problem".

**Edit:** For JMX remoting to work, you'll need to make a decision about authenticating. It's better to do it in 3 distinct steps:

1. basic setup with
   `-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false` then
2. add a
   password file (`-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.password.file`). [See
   here for instructions.](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/management/monitoring-and-management-using-jmx-technology.html#GUID-08484F70-31A5-4B87-A7DD-2BCCD2E6580D) +
   `-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false` and then
3. set up SSL.

Comment: Does this approach exclude using `JAVA_OPTS` method below?

Comment: I tried this method (Option 3) with a Java service running within a Docker container, and had trouble connecting to it from outside the container.  I'll have to do a small sample project to explore this idea better.

Comment: is this `(appname).conf` file documented somewhere?

Comment: @OleksandrSh, the documentation is here: https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.3.2.RELEASE/reference/html/deployment.html#deployment-script-customization-conf-file

Comment: Option 1 errors out (JDK 11, Spring Boot 2.3.2) with
`Error: Password file not found: {skipped}
jdk.internal.agent.AgentConfigurationError
 at jdk.management.agent/sun.management.jmxremote.ConnectorBootstrap.checkPasswordFile(ConnectorBootstrap.java:572)
 at jdk.management.agent/sun.management.jmxremote.ConnectorBootstrap.startRemoteConnectorServer(ConnectorBootstrap.java:436)
 at jdk.management.agent/jdk.internal.agent.Agent.startAgent(Agent.java:447)
 at jdk.management.agent/jdk.internal.agent.Agent.startAgent(Agent.java:599)`

Comment: Well, Option 1 (`-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=$JMX_REGISTRY_PORT` + 
`-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.rmi.port=$RMI_SERVER_PORT`) is missing the required property: `-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false` or true with the setup from @Popyeye answer. It's just not working without this in OpenJDK 11. That's the root cause for the `Error: Password file not found`.

Comment: @DKroot Java 11 is no different than Java 7+ in this regard. The authenticate flag is true by default and you're supposed to configure a `jmxremote.password` file. Setting the flag to false is a security vulnerability so don't do it unless you're on a non-prod machine.

Comment: Yes, I went with @Popeye's setup. Overall, JMX configuration was incredibly hairy. I think it's better to do it in 3 distinct steps: 1) basic setup with `-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false` then 2) add a password file and `-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false` and then 3) set up SSL

Comment: @DKroot That's reasonable advice. Feel free to update the ticket to say so if you like, or I can if you'd prefer not to.

Comment: @inanutshellus Sure. Which ticket would I need to update?

Comment: @DKroot Ha! I said "ticket" out of habit. I meant add your advice to the SO Answer above.

Comment: @inanutshellus Done. OMG: you can edit somebody else's answer! It's the first time I did it on SO. My own answers: sure. Somebody else's: blew my mind. :)

Answer (score 41):

Add the following JVM Properties in "$JAVA_OPTS" (in your application):

```
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=<PORT_NUMBER> -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false -Djava.rmi.server.hostname=<HOST'S_IP>
```

In the Jconsole/Visual VM use the following to connect:

```
service:jmx:rmi:///jndi/rmi://<HOST'S_IP>:<PORT_NUMBER>/jmxrmi
```

It doesn't enable security, but will help you to connect to the remote server.

Comment: This did the trick for me ... thank you. It did not work until I added the -Djava.rmi.server.hostname. I was able to connect via jconsole like this: ip:port

Comment: These params have to be used via the `java` command line. Setting them in JAVA_OPTS didn't work for me for Spring Boot 2.3.2. Here is a longer blog post: https://medium.com/@cl4r1ty/docker-spring-boot-and-java-opts-ba381c818fa2. (Docker does not matter, `JAVA_OPTS="..." java -jar` doesn't work either.)

Answer (score 6):

A tested approach on Java 1.8.0_71 and Spring Boot(1.3.3.RELEASE).
Append below parameters to JVM arguments for monitored JVM.

```
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=12348 -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=true -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.rmi.port=12349 -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.password.file=/somewhere/jmxremote.password -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.access.file=/somewhere/jmx/jmxremote.access
```

The `com.sun.management.jmxremote.port` is used to define the fixed RMI registry port, and the `com.sun.management.jmxremote.rmi.port` is used to instruct JVM to use fixed RMI port, but NOT use random one.

By setting this, I am able to connect JVM client from remote host to the monitored JVM via a firewall just opening 12348 and 12349 port.

I tested using `java -jar cmdline-jmxclient-0.10.3.jar user:pwd hostip:12348` on a remote machine, which generates below output(shortened just for demonstration).

```
java.lang:type=Runtime
java.lang:name=PS Scavenge,type=GarbageCollector
Tomcat:J2EEApplication=none,J2EEServer=none,WebModule=//localhost/,j2eeType=Filter,name=requestContextFilter
java.nio:name=mapped,type=BufferPool
Tomcat:host=localhost,type=Host
java.lang:name=Compressed Class Space,type=MemoryPool
.......
```

The jar is downloaded from [Here](http://crawler.archive.org/cmdline-jmxclient/downloads.html).

Comment: I tested this approach successfully in OpenJDK 11 with 2 improvements: 1. Using the same port for JMX and RMI. 2. Omitting `-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote`: this is no longer needed.

Answer (score 0):

Another alternative

[Reference for jmxremote.password and jmxremote.access files](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/management/monitoring-and-management-using-jmx-technology.html#GUID-D4CBA2D6-2E24-4856-A7D8-62B3DFFB76EA)

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.DependsOn;
import org.springframework.jmx.support.ConnectorServerFactoryBean;
import org.springframework.remoting.rmi.RmiRegistryFactoryBean;

@Configuration
public class ConfigureRMI {

    @Value("${jmx.rmi.password.file:/tmp/jmxremote.password}")
    private String passwordFile;

    @Value("${jmx.rmi.access.file:/tmp/jmxremote.access}")
    private String accessFile;

    @Value("${jmx.rmi.port:19999}")
    private Integer rmiPort;

    @Bean
    public RmiRegistryFactoryBean rmiRegistry() {
        final RmiRegistryFactoryBean rmiRegistryFactoryBean = new RmiRegistryFactoryBean();
        rmiRegistryFactoryBean.setPort(rmiPort);
        rmiRegistryFactoryBean.setAlwaysCreate(true);
        return rmiRegistryFactoryBean;
    }

    @Bean
    @DependsOn("rmiRegistry")
    public ConnectorServerFactoryBean connectorServerFactoryBean() throws Exception {
        final ConnectorServerFactoryBean connectorServerFactoryBean = new ConnectorServerFactoryBean();
        connectorServerFactoryBean.setObjectName("connector:name=rmi");
        Map<String, Object> properties = new HashMap<>();
        properties.put("jmx.remote.x.password.file", passwordFile);
        properties.put("jmx.remote.x.access.file", accessFile);
        connectorServerFactoryBean.setEnvironmentMap(properties);
        connectorServerFactoryBean.setServiceUrl(String.format("service:jmx:rmi:///jndi/rmi://:%s/jmxrmi", rmiPort));
        return connectorServerFactoryBean;
    }
}
```