# spring boot actuator connect jmx programmatically

Tags: spring-boot, spring-boot-actuator, spring-jmx

I'd like to use the `shutdown` endpoint of my Spring Boot 2.0.1 application from the command line. For that I have only added the `spring-boot-starter-actuator` to my Gradle file and enabled the `shutdown` endpoint in the configuration.

I also created a very simple tool that tries to connect via JMX to the running application.

Snippet:

```
String url = "service:jmx:rmi:///jndi/rmi://127.0.01:<which port?>/jmxrmi";
JMXServiceURL serviceUrl = new JMXServiceURL(url);
JMXConnectorFactory.connect(serviceUrl, null); <-- KAPOW!
```

JMX is working because I can use `jconsole` to connect locally. I just have no clue how to do it programmatically.

Any other attempts to explicitly set a port as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33089641/1651116) didn't work. Any hints?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's probably easier to [enable jolokia](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.0.2.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#production-ready-jolokia) rather than using RMI; then you can simply

```
curl http://localhost:8080/actuator/jolokia/exec/org.springframework.boot:type=Admin,name=SpringApplication/shutdown
```

**EDIT**

If you prefer to use RMI, refer to the [Spring Framework JMX Documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/integration.html#jmx-jsr160).

**Server app:**

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class So50392589Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(So50392589Application.class, args);
    }

    @Bean
    public RmiRegistryFactoryBean rmi() {
        RmiRegistryFactoryBean rmi = new RmiRegistryFactoryBean();
        rmi.setPort(1099);
        return rmi;
    }

    @Bean
    public ConnectorServerFactoryBean server() throws Exception {
        ConnectorServerFactoryBean fb = new ConnectorServerFactoryBean();
        fb.setObjectName("connector:name=rmi");
        fb.setServiceUrl("service:jmx:rmi://localhost/jndi/rmi://localhost:1099/myconnector");
        return fb;
    }

}
```

**Client app:**

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class JmxClient {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new SpringApplicationBuilder(JmxClient.class)
            .web(WebApplicationType.NONE)
            .run(args);
    }

    @Bean
    public ApplicationRunner runner(MBeanServerConnection jmxConnector) {
        return args -> {
            jmxConnector.invoke(new ObjectName("org.springframework.boot:type=Admin,name=SpringApplication"),
                    "shutdown", new Object[0], new String[0]);
        };
    }

    @Bean
    public MBeanServerConnectionFactoryBean jmxConnector() throws Exception {
        MBeanServerConnectionFactoryBean jmx = new MBeanServerConnectionFactoryBean();
        jmx.setServiceUrl("service:jmx:rmi://localhost/jndi/rmi://localhost:1099/myconnector");
        return jmx;
    }

}
```

Comment: I would have preferred if I didn't have to make this available through HTTP. It should only be a configuration setting to enable `/actuator/shutdown` if I understood everything correctly. However, your example looks complicated enough so that it won't be discovered too easily by someone dabbling around.

Comment: If you prefer to use RMI, see the edit to my answer.

Comment: Is it possible to set the port using a property without having to write all this boilerplate code?

Comment: How do we set that `8080` port in the `cUrl` example with jolokia if my Spring Boot app is a non web app? @GaryRussell

Comment: Don’t ask new questions in comments on 3 year old answers. Actuator just needs the web starter. That doesn’t mean you need to add a controller to your app.

Answer (score -1):

There is a much simpler approach if you do not need to connect to the app remotely using the [jcmd](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/tools/jcmd.html#GUID-59153599-875E-447D-8D98-0078A5778F05) tool introduced in Java SE 7, and the [Attach API](https://www.infoworld.com/article/2073919/groovy--jmx--and-the-attach-api.html) introduced in Java SE 6.

I've written a blog post that explains this in detail. It's too big to simply copy-paste here, following is the link to the relevant section.

https://blog.asarkar.com/technical/grpc-kubernetes-spring/#jmx

This is not a duplicate answer because when the question was asked, this answer didn't exist. This answer has already been tailored to this question; let's not get trigger happy mods.