# How to use SpringBoot actuator over JMX

Tags: spring-boot, jmx, spring-boot-actuator

I am having existing Spring Boot application and I want to do monitoring the application through actuator.I tried with http endpoints and it is working fine for me. Instead of http end points I need JMX end points for my existing running application.

Answer (score 3):

If you add `spring-boot-starter-actuator`dependency in your build.gradle or pom.xml file you will have JMX bean enabled by default as well as HTTP Endpoints.

You can use JConsole in order to view your JMX exposed beans. You'll find more info about this [here](https://www.logicbig.com/tutorials/spring-framework/spring-boot/accessing-jmx-actuator-endpoints.html).

More details about how to access JMX endpoints [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50392589/spring-boot-actuator-connect-jmx-programmatically).

Comment: How can I access the JMX endpoints from another client application? I am having a spring boot client application where I will get the info from actuator jmx endpoints and need to log the info getting from jmx endpoints.

Comment: I am new to Spring Boot actuator . Which mode will be the good choice ? Whether "JMX" or "REST"

Comment: It's not REST, it's HTTP. REST is an architectural style o developing applications. The http endpoints that are exposed by Actuator are delivering you metrics in Prometheus format, IMO the best choice is to use that Prometheus metrics, because they are the defacto standard of metrics in Cloud Native World. Even cncf.io has promoted Prometheus Metrics.

Comment: Thanks for the update. Is there any comparison document available between  "JMX" and "HTTP" where we can get the exact pros and cons of each mode .

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you're using a Docker image where the entry point is the Spring Boot app using `java` in which case the PID is "1" and so would the Attach API's Virtual Machine ID.  You can implement a health probe as follows.

```java
import com.sun.tools.attach.spi.AttachProvider;
import java.util.Map;
import javax.management.MBeanServerConnection;
import javax.management.ObjectName;
import javax.management.remote.JMXConnectorFactory;
import javax.management.remote.JMXServiceURL;

public class HealthProbe {

  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

    final var attachProvider = AttachProvider.providers().get(0);
    final var virtualMachine = attachProvider.attachVirtualMachine("1");
    final var jmxServiceUrl = virtualMachine.startLocalManagementAgent();

    try (final var jmxConnection = JMXConnectorFactory.connect(new JMXServiceURL(jmxServiceUrl))) {
      final MBeanServerConnection serverConnection = jmxConnection.getMBeanServerConnection();

      @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
      final var healthResult =
          (Map<String, ?>)
              serverConnection.invoke(
                  new ObjectName("org.springframework.boot:type=Endpoint,name=Health"),
                  "health",
                  new Object[0],
                  new String[0]);
      if ("UP".equals(healthResult.get("status"))) {
        System.exit(0);
      } else {
        System.exit(1);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

This will use the Attach API and make the original process start a local management agent.

The `org.springframework.boot:type=Endpoint,name=Health` object instance would have it's `health` method invoked which will provide a `Map` version of the `/actuator/health` output.  From there the value of `status` should be `UP` if things are ok.

Then exit with `0` if ok, or `1` otherwise.

This can be embedded in an existing Spring Boot app so long as `loader.main` is set.  The following is the `HEALTHCHECK` probe I used

```
HEALTHCHECK --interval=5s --start-period=60s \
    CMD ["java", \
         "-Dloader.main=net.trajano.swarm.gateway.healthcheck.HealthProbe", \
         "org.springframework.boot.loader.PropertiesLauncher" ]
```

This is the technique I used in [distroless Docker Image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73172864/how-do-you-do-spring-health-check-using-the-dockerfile-healthcheck-when-using-di).

*Side note:* Don't try to put this in a `CommandLineRunner` interface because it will try to pull the configuration from the main app and you likely won't need the whole web stack.