# How do you do Spring Health Check using the Dockerfile HEALTHCHECK when using distroless?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, docker, distroless

Since [distroless](https://github.com/GoogleContainerTools/distroless) does not contain a shell or package manager, if I were to use `gcr.io/distroless/java17-debian11`, how would I implement something like

```
HEALTHCHECK --interval=5s --start-period=60s \
    CMD curl -sfo /dev/null http://localhost:8080/actuator/health
```

Also I'm on Docker Swarm so there's no "external http probe"

On a Java app/Spring Boot I can have [multiple mains](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57959386/running-spring-boot-with-multiple-main-classes) and one of them can connect to [Spring actuator or some custom JMX endpoint](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56105364/how-to-use-springboot-actuator-over-jmx) that I had provided [an answer for](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73180551/242042).  However, that's extra custom code.

Comment: Hi, any luck? I have similar problem [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75962015/cannot-hit-a-health-check-endpoint-from-dockerized-spring-boot-app)

Comment: Having a custom JMX endpoint is actually helpful and you can have more complex tests for health.